# AppBar Button Animation on Add/Remove

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a WinRT app in which an AppBar button can be one of two buttons depending upon what is selected. Changing from one button to another is straightforward, however it is lacking the visual fluidity we strive for with WinRT.

The visual behavior I am looking for is also seen in the Mail app that ships with Windows 8. If you select a message and bring up the bottom AppBar, tapping the "Mark as Read/Unread" buttons results in a nice transform effect between the two buttons.

Does anyone know if this is a pre-rolled animation or do I have to implement it by hand (or even better, is there a solution out there already)?

Comment: Have you tried using blend?

Comment: Not yet. I would rather use a pre-rolled/supported theme animation if it is available. (I'm hoping it's in the dox and I just haven't found it yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available transitions are in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation namespace. [Check out what is there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj218361.aspx) and if you don't see what you are looking for then you will have to create your own.

The transition that looks most similar to me is AddDeleteThemeTransition, though the effect is only present when app bar items are added/removed and not when the app bar is opened.

Here's an example of its use

```
    <AppBar>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="Search" Style="{StaticResource SearchAppBarButtonStyle}" />
                <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to do the "zoom in/out" portion of the transition...instead it seems to apply a fade in/out effect.

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding an item as in the mail example you describe?

Comment: The available transitions are in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation namespace. Check out what is there and if you don't see what you are looking for then you will have to create your own. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj218361.aspx

Comment: I'll mark this as "correct" due to the follow-up comment. Thanks for the feedback!